# How do you properly delete Dependent entites when updating the Principal entity?

Tags: ef-core-2.0

I'm having an issue with EFCore 2.0 where its impossible to properly delete dependent entities when updating the prinicipal entity. Here's my code:

**Mapping**

```
public class BlueprintMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Blueprint>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Blueprint> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("blueprint").HasKey(t => t.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("blueprint_id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasMany<Objective>().WithOne(x => x.Blueprint).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

public class ObjectiveMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Objective>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Objective> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("objective").HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("objective_id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Blueprint).WithMany(y => y.Objectives).HasForeignKey("blueprint_id");   
    }
}
```

**Update WebApi Call**

Get from context

```
var blueprint = await blueprintContext.Blueprints
    .Where(x => id == x.Id)
    .Include(x => x.Objectives)           
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Remove objectives from blueprint entity (Objectives is ICollection, the dependent entity

```
blueprint.Objectives.Remove(objective);
```

// Get a new context

```
var blueprintContext = await _blueprintContextFactory.CreateContext();
```

Blueprint entity AND Blueprint from context have 0 objectives

```
int x = await blueprintContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Get WebApi Call**

Get from context

```
return await blueprintContext.Blueprints
    .Where(x => id == x.Id)
    .Include(x => x.Objectives)         
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

blueprint has 2 objectives again.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant entity model. Also `RemoveObjective` method. Also restructure the problematic code to show the exact sequence of operations - e.g. create context, get blueprint, remove objective, save changes. Basically [mcve].

Comment: @IvanStoev, I've updated in response to your comments. The problematic code is shown as the exact sequence of operations. You could also combine the second Get call and the results would be the same. So Get Blueprint, Remove objectives, SaveChanges on the context, Get Blueprint is the full flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. The first context tracks the objectives being removed. When a new context is generated to save the changes, it doesn't know about the objectives being removed so they remain and regenerate. In other words, the Update request is using multiple contexts instead of just 1 per request and this is unacceptable by EF Core's design.